# a specific method for numpy, scipy resampling

Tags: python, biopython

I have a numpy array. I want to resample that numpy array to a specific value say 10.

```
 X = [[  6.99749994  17.76250029   5.01699996]
     [ 10.5150001   18.28000021   4.06300002]
     [ 12.47374988  19.4937501    6.93949986]
     [ 15.38050032  21.92675018   6.68924999]
     [ 17.19525003  19.25349998   7.71924984]
     [ 15.75849962  17.17449951   5.07899988]
     [ 16.83874989  19.46924973   2.56125003]
     [ 20.24999952  19.40649986   3.77824998]
     [ 20.32649994  15.83099985   3.59350002]
     [ 19.17724943  15.48849988   0.23099999]
     [ 21.44624996  18.01575041  -0.98599999]
     [ 24.13700008  16.26849985   0.35250001]
     [ 23.45549965  13.07250023  -0.88625002]
     [ 22.66449976  14.09524989  -4.22149998]
     [ 25.57133357  15.34866651  -4.50566673]
     [ 27.54475021  12.71549988  -4.02225   ]
     [ 25.7732501   11.273       -6.82424998]
     [ 26.65899976  13.21299966  -9.15133333]
     [ 27.97424984  12.19199991 -12.32075   ]
     [ 26.63675022   8.88499999 -11.40549994]]
```

Right now my numpy array in 3x20 dimensions. I want to resample to 3x10. 
How can I do that using Biopython, numpy or scipy?

this is resampling function which I need to convert to python. pastebin.com/JsGeNyLp
where input is numpy array and N is any integer value e.g.10

Comment: What does "resample that numpy array to a specific value say 10" mean?  Could you edit your question to include your expected output?

Comment: it means right now my matrix is 3x20. I want to resample it into 3x10

Comment: What should the new values be? Interpolated\calculated in some way, or simply ditch half at random?

Comment: actually this is resampling function which I need to convert to python. http://pastebin.com/JsGeNyLp

Comment: Might wanna include that in the question, a specific method for resampling sounds kinda relevant.

Comment: @M4rtini : I v changed title accordingly

Comment: @sam You should really explain what you want to do instead of expecting us to read through undocumented MATLAB with extremely terse and opaque variable names.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus : you are right. I am seeing the matlab code. I have not learn matlab so I am getting difficulty as there is no guide available too.

Comment: @sam I have deciphered the MATLAB, and pieced together its function in the form of some Python and explained it below.

Answer (score 4):

While the question is a bit vague, if all you're looking to do is randomly select some number of elements from a `numpy` array at random, python has a convenient `random` module that will let you do just that:

```
import random

resampled_X = random.random_sample(X, 10)
```

Looking at your linked MATLAB code, it looks like you might be looking for some 1d interpolation in addition to this. Again, hard to say exactly without more details in your question, but `scipy` in fact has an `interp1d` function just like MATLAB. You would use it like so:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
x = range(30)
y = [i**2 for i in x]
# quadratic can be replaced with linear, cubic, or just a number for polynomial degree
new_function = interp1d(x, y, 'quadratic')
new_function(1.5)
>>> 2.25
```

After reading through your code I can offer the following translation of it into `numpy` and `scipy` code, but it's an extremely unintuitive definition for "resampling"

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import intep1d

def resample(X, N):
    norms = [0] + [np.linalg.norm(X[:,i] - X[:,i-1]) for i in range(1,X.shape[1])]
    cumdel = np.cumsum(norms)/sum(norms)
    solution_space = np.linspace(0,1, N)
    new_function = lambda i: interp1d(cumdel, X[i,:])
    return np.array([new_function(i)(solution_space) for i in range(X.shape[0])]).T
```

Basically what it looks like this code is doing is this:

- Constructing a list of the magnitude of changes from one entry in the array to the next. (The norms list)
- Normalizing that list with a cumsum, so it becomes a list of "percent of the way through all of the changes in this list" (cumdel)
- Interpolates along each column (of the three in your example) and then sampling from a linspace going from zero to one (solution_space) according to the `n` added (return line)

Kind of a weird thing to be doing, but that's what it's doing. Let me know if you have any more problems.

Comment: What about norms = np.linalg.norm(X[1:] - X[:-1], axis=0).tolist() rather than the list comprehension? And since you `import numpy as np` you may not want to use `numpy.`

Comment: @chthonicdaemon sounds reasonable. Wrote that bit of code in a hurry.

Comment: it has error : IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
but thanks. I understand the code

Comment: @sam That's probably because you've got your axes flipped. The matrix in the description is `20,3` rather than `3,20`. If you transpose it then this should work.

Comment: @sam Oh, whoops. Looks like chthonicdaemon's code was also totally broken. Didn't bother to check, switching it back to old list comp.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon axis is not actually a kwarg that norm can take.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus It's not the axis kwarg that is the problem, it is the way the subtraction worked - I was subtracting rows from one another when in fact it should hav been columns. `norms = [0] + np.linalg.norm(X[:,1:] - X[:,:-1], axis=0).tolist()` is correct. Sorry about that.